# Selection is not visibile while dragging

Tags: firefox, mouse, thunderbird, 23.04

In Ubuntu 23.04, in most applications and in most cases (but, unfortunately, *not* always) I cannot see the text selection while dragging my mouse.

Example:

- while writing this question, I press and hold my left mouse button on any text area of this page
- I drag the mouse as usual to create a selection, but nothing happens, like I was just moving the pointer
- finally, when I release the left mouse button the selection appears

Of course this is not the expected behavior and it has many drawbacks (i.e. you don't know what you selected until the selection is already done).

This happens in several application, for example in Firefox and Thunderbird.
I didn't notice this behavior with previous Ubuntu versions.

Is it a new "feature" I can tweak somewhere?

Comment: are you using the dark theme? I have noticed with dark theme that selecting multiple files in Nautilus the selection of multiple files is not so apparent but they are selected nonetheless if you look carefully. As for "tweaking" try turning off dark mode and trying that to see if there is a difference.

Comment: @graham yes, I'm using the dark theme. When I release the mouse button the selection becomes visible in blue. But while dragging is completely invisible, even looking carefully.

Comment: did you try without dark theme set?

Comment: @graham mmm... I need more time to investigate. It seems there are more serious issues with Firefox and Thunderbird - perhaps also this one is related.